# Different versions of java and javac on Travis CI

Tags: java, travis-ci

I've configured a build on Travis CI with the following config (.travis.yml) :

```
language: java

jdk:
  - openjdk8
```

But here's what is displayed in the job log on Travis :

```
$ java -Xmx32m -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-8u141-b15-3~14.04-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
$ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
javac 9.0.1
```

Versions of *java* and *javac* are not matching : **1.8.0_141** vs **9.0.1**.
Is there a problem ?

### Quick test with Docker

I've just tried to display the versions in a docker container, here are the results :

```
> docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

And :

```
> docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk javac -version
javac 1.8.0_181
```

In this case, it matches.